# How to check if Nightmare JS is running in debug mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

Is there a way to determine if my Nightmare script is running with debugging output?

For example, to launch Nightmare with debug output, I'd use:

`DEBUG=nightmare node myscript.js`; otherwise, I'd use `node myscript.js`

Within `myscript.js`, how can I determine if the script is running with `DEBUG=nightmare`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `process.env.DEBUG` to get `DEBUG`'s value.